# Don't require a log message in svn

Tags: svn

I am using command-line svn.   How do I stop it from requiring me to specify a log message on commits?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if I wanted to add a fixed argument to every invocation of a command, I'd use a shell alias -- but that doesn't really work for `svn`, since you'd only want to apply it to the `commit` subcommand.

I suppose you could alias `svn` to a wrapper script that checks to see if its first argument is `commit` or `ci`, then invoke the real `svn`, jamming in an empty `-m` option if necessary. But I would neither write, nor advocate the use of, such a tool. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `svn commit -m "They don't make Sunday."`

Comment: That's still specifying a log message. But indeed maybe the OP means "stop it from sending me to a text editor to write the log message". If so, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is specified as a commit hook on the server side of things. If you don't have access to the server you usually can't change this.

Comment: `svn commit` on the command line dumps you into a text editor, if you don't specify a log message when you commit.  I assume that's what JoelFan wants to work around.

Comment: I do have access to the server... I just can't figure out how to take out this hook